# How to integrate PayU money with Cordova Application(Hybrid App)

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, payu

I want to integrate PayU Money Payment gateway in my IONIC Cordova app. I got the doc from PayU team. There is mentioned one post api need to call. But problem is, what should be the correct JSON for the POST API? And How to create WEB VIEW in cordova app for PayU Money? And what should redirect URL?

Below test url provided by payu money.

POST URL: https://test.payu.in/_payment

I called below url via HTTP post request. But just returning html whole template page. And how to render it in WEB VIEW?

Can someone help me with steps, how to do so?

Comment: Yes. JavaScript and AnguarJS.

Answer (score 3):

Harish use this https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-plugin-wizViewManager plugin to load your "returning html whole template page".

Comment: Thanks. I will implement this and will get back to you in case of issue with plugin.

Comment: @HarishPatidar Can you please share the procedure of how to integrate the payumoney with Cordova. I am facing hard time integrating it.

Comment: @NukulGhosh I tried a lot but not able to integrate with cordova app itself. What I have done is, I have created server side pages for the same and opening in InAppBrowser. I am passing required parameters from app to server via api and according to that server is returning payumoney url and same url I am opening in InAppBrowser window. Once transaction is success or declined,  SUCCESS or ERROR will open in InAppBrowser. I am checking page URL in InAppBrowser event listener. So according to that I am closing the InAppBrowser window and showing message to user.

Comment: @HarishPatidar Can you attach sample code of InAppBrowser for payumoney payment gateway integration?

Comment: @HareshKumar That code in don' have in my hand. That is developed by server team and they have provided me one web page url. That I was opening in InAppBrowser.